# How to create blurred Graphics3D objects?

Tags: graphics3d

Initially I was interested in renderring a 3D analog of a blurred disk like this

```
DensityPlot[1 - HeavisideLambda[(x^2 + y^2)/8]/2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 FrameTicks -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

The only idea that came to my mind was playing with `Opacity`, which gives hardly an impressive result:

```
Graphics3D[{Orange}~Join~
   Table[{Opacity[i], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1 - i]}, {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}] // 
  Flatten]
```

[image]

So, **1) is it possible to get "true" blurred ball and 2) how to extrapolate this idea to other 3D objects?**

Comment: a finer spacing in `Table` makes it "blurry"...

Comment: In simulator graphics you used to have a technique called *billboarding* which involved a flat image that was put perpendicular to the line of sight and that was rotated as to remain perpendicular when the observer moved. Trees can be made to appear amazingly 3D that way. It works best with object that have lots of symmetry. You could try that here as well.

Comment: By "true", I guess you want an actual 3D object?  Otherwise, you could use `Blur[Graphics3D[Sphere[],Boxed->False],10]`

Comment: @MarkMcClure, exactly. It should be possible to combine this blurred object with other (non-blurred) 3D objects.

Comment: @faleichik Yeah, I figured.

Comment: Perhaps an idea could be combine an unblurred image of a Graphics3D with a blurred one and having their view dynamically controlled. I am not too deft at image processing nor I have time now, but this will show the idea.

Comment: `Overlay[{Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]],
  Dynamic@Blur[Graphics3D[Cuboid[], Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> vp], 10]}, 2, 1]`. Far from perfect

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries You can do billboarding in 3D graphics with `Inset`.

Comment: @Rojo, very cool, I can see the un-blurred version behind at some points.

Comment: @Rojo You could add `SphericalRegion -> True` and post your code that as an answer. I would be glad to upvote it.

Comment: @belisarius, ok. I was reluctant because as it is it didn't offer a way to mix unblurred and blurred 3D graphics

Comment: Honestly, the only productive way to solve this is to export the 3D object (e.g. as `STL` or even `POV`) and then process it in Blender (e.g.). Even the good old pov-ray has diffuse scattering media that can be used as the interior of objects. Then you get real ray tracing quality and more realism such as diffuse shadows, being able to add turbulence, etc etc. MMA is simply not the right tool at this point.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**UPDATE: latest Mathematica 9 functionality**

This is very easy now with latest Mathematica 9 functionality. Just use **Image3D** or **Raster3D** functions:

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[With[{step = .03}, 
    ParallelTable[Exp[-(i^2 + j^2 + k^2)^4/.99], 
    {k, -1.2, 1.2, step}, {i, -1.2, 1.2, step}, {j, -1.2, 1.2, step}]]];

Image3D[data, ColorFunction -> #, Axes -> True, 
   ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {Automatic, "XRay"}
```

[image]

**-------- OLDER VERSIONS ----------------**

**METHOD 1 - volumetric rendering - from scratch**

I will use ideas from [**this post**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/how-to-show-solid-bodies-using-volumetric-rendering/6252#6252) by Yu-Sung. First create data for 3D texture:

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[
        With[{step = .05}, 
        ParallelTable[{1, 0, 0, Exp[-(i^2 + j^2 + k^2)^4/.8]}, 
        {k, -1, 1, step}, {i, -1, 1, step}, {j, -1, 1, step}]]];
```

Next create many polygons with applied texture:

```
Graphics3D[{
  EdgeForm[],
  Opacity[.4],(*Overall transparency of the textured polygons*)
  Texture[data],(*Set volumetric texture*)
  With[{pts = 
     Table[{{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, z}, {1, 1, z}, {0, 1, z}}, {z, 0, 
       1, .05}]}, Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}},
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Background -> Black, RotationAction -> "Clip",
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2], White],
 ImageSize -> 4 {100, 100},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 Axes -> False,
 BaseStyle -> {RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> 100}}]
```

Below are the views in different directions. It's pretty fast:

[image]

**METHOD 2 - volumetric rendering - CUDA - on GPU from built-in interface**

Again, I will use ideas from [**this post**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/how-to-show-solid-bodies-using-volumetric-rendering/6252#6252) by Yu-Sung. We will use built-in interface [`CUDAVolumetricRender`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/ref/CUDAVolumetricRender.html) to render our 3D fading out texture on GPU.

Make sure you have latest CUDA paclet - [**read this tutorial**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/tutorial/Setup.html).

Create data which are good for 3D texture understood by [`CUDAVolumetricRender`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/ref/CUDAVolumetricRender.html)

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[
   With[{step = .05}, 
    Table[Round[255 Exp[-(i^2 + j^2 + k^2)^1/.8]], {k, -1, 1, 
      step}, {i, -1, 1, step}, {j, -1, 1, step}]]];
```

Load CUDA package and follow Yu-Sung CUDA cooking recipes as shortly given below (see details in [**this post**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/how-to-show-solid-bodies-using-volumetric-rendering/6252#6252))

```
<< CUDALink`
Clear[prepareCUDAVolumeData];
prepareCUDAVolumeData::arg = 
  "The argument should be an integer array of depth 3.";
prepareCUDAVolumeData[array_] /; ArrayQ[array, 3, IntegerQ] := 
  Module[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} = Dimensions[array];
   Developer`ToPackedArray[
    Partition[#, x] & /@ Partition[Flatten[array], x*z]]];
prepareCUDAVolumeData[___] /; (Message[prepareCUDAVolumeData::arg];
    False) := Null;
CUDAVolumetricRender[prepareCUDAVolumeData[data]]
```

After playing with options of the interface (see control positions) and the usual zooming of *Mathematica* 3D graphics you can get this beautiful view:

[image]

**METHOD 3 - opaque spheres ---------------------------------------------**

This is not ideal, but just a demonstration of a concept. We can approximate a complex volume opacity by filling the volume with small transparent spheres. The more spheres we have and the smaller and closer they are the better. In the example below I even make spheres to overlap to mask the gaps between them. Computation and rendering of 64000 transparent spheres is not short and it is tedious to rotate that 3D object. Due to cubic grid only certain viewing direction result in the image below (I set that with `ViewPoint` option). I suspect that cubic close packed (face-centered cubic fcc) and hexagonal close-packed (hcp) will show more uniform viewing from various perspectives. I may add the code for those later.

```
Block[{r = 20},
 Graphics3D[
  Table[{Red, Opacity[7 N@Exp[-(i^2 + j^2 + k^2)/(r/2)^2]], 
     Sphere[{i, j, k}, 3]}, {i, -r, r}, {j, -r, r}, {k, -r,
     r}], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @R.M It makes it look somewhat better - I added `"DepthPeelingLayers"`. Some layering can be seen, but that is diminished by amount of layers. It is a blurry sphere because you can see box through the sphere fading outline. That what I was going for. But I was not able to recreate the view you posted. Can you do //Options and send me for current code?

Comment: Hmmm... I can't seem to repro that view now that I've closed the notebook. I'm deleting my comment, because it could've been some residual settings that messed it up. I'll play around some more later in the evening when I get some time and if I can repro it, I'll definitely get the options :)

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps an idea could be combine an unblurred image of a Graphics3D with a blurred one and having their view dynamically controlled. I am not too deft at image processing nor I have time now, but this will show the idea.

```
DynamicModule[{vp = Options[Graphics3D, ViewPoint][[1, 2]],
  va = Options[Graphics3D, ViewAngle][[1, 2]],
  vv = Options[Graphics3D, ViewVertical][[1, 2]],
  vc = Options[Graphics3D, ViewCenter][[1, 2]],
  vr = Options[Graphics3D, ViewRange][[1, 2]]}, 
 Overlay[{Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
    ViewAngle -> Dynamic[va], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv], 
    ViewCenter -> Dynamic[vc], ViewRange -> Dynamic[vr], 
    SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False], 
   Dynamic@Blur[
     Graphics3D[Cuboid[], SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, 
      ViewPoint -> vp, ViewAngle -> va, ViewVertical -> vv, 
      ViewCenter -> vc, ViewRange -> vr], 10]}, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: `DynamicModule` is more appropriate here, otherwise we're effectively leaking symbols out of the `Module`.

Comment: @Szabolcs edited

Comment: This seems not work in 10.2?