# Is it possible to produce anaglyphs with Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d

I'd like to prepare some presentations in Mathematica to help students visualize functions of two variables (it's a usual calculus course).  I thought it would be both cool and useful to have the graphs as red/cyan [anaglyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D).  Is it possible to do that, and if yes, how?

**Edit:** Simon Woods' answer below is great, but it produces a static image.  I'd prefer an interactive version (rotatable - is it a word? - with a mouse); if this is not possible, then I'd like to have at least an animation.  (I guess the latter shouldn't be too hard - I'd only have to put suitable commands in some loop, export the images and mount them as an animation; the point is, I'm a Mathemathica newbie and don't know (yet) how to do it - but I can probably figure that out on my own.)

Comment: by anaglyph, do you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D)?

Comment: Yes, I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: Check out the StereoImagery package by Mark Fisher: http://www.markfisher.net/~mefisher/mma/mathematica.html and a nice example by @Vitaly http://vimeo.com/15262935

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the basic idea is to create two slightly different views and combine them in the red and (green + blue) channels.

```
p = Plot3D[Sin[x y]^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];

{r, g} = ColorConvert[
 Image[Show[p, ViewPoint -> {3 Sin[#], 3 Cos[#], 2} &[# Degree]],
   ImageSize -> {360, 275}], "Grayscale"] & /@ {141, 139};

ColorCombine[{r, g, g}]
```

[image]

A simple way to animate is just to change the `ViewPoint` in a loop and `Export` the individual frames. I use some software called VirtualDub to combine the images into a movie or animated gif:

```
Do[{r, g} = ColorConvert[
     Image[Show[p, SphericalRegion -> True, 
       ViewPoint -> {3 Sin[#], 3 Cos[#], 2} &[# Degree]], 
      ImageSize -> {360, 275}], "Grayscale"] & /@ {2 a + 1, 2 a - 1}; 
 Export["frame" <> ToString[a] <> ".bmp", ColorCombine[{r, g, g}]]
 , {a, 0, 44}]
```

[image]

Comment: It works for me, but I think you should remove the tick labels as they are vertically displaced somewhat.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you keep the ViewCenter the same in both pictures?

Comment: Thanks, this is *very* nice.  However, it is "just an image", I cannot e.g. rotate it interactively.  I'll modify the question once again;).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, the ViewCenter is the same in both images I think.

Comment: @mbork, interactive rotation is probably possible, but I don't know how to do it!

Comment: +1 nice. Perhaps if no other options appear interactivity can be achieved with [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6258/109) idea

Comment: Actually, what I meant to say is that you may have to correct for automatic scaling of the object by Mathematica. When a rotated view is quite different from the original, mma may rescale and as ViewCenter is {1/2,1/2,1/2} by default in scaled coordinates this may have an impact.

Comment: Could you adapt the code [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/extract-values-for-viewmatrix-from-a-graphics3d) to produce a stereo pair? You'd need to shift the viewpoint.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, okay I see what you mean. I had to use `SphericalRegion -> True` for the animation to avoid that automatic scaling.

Answer (score 4):

The idea of interactive rotation of the anaglyph has caught my attention. I propose the following:

```
Manipulate[
ColorCombine@
Flatten@(ColorSeparate[
    Image[Show[pl, ViewPoint -> {2 Sin[(\[Alpha] + #[[1]]) Degree], 
        2 Cos[(\[Alpha] + #[[1]]) Degree], 
        3 Cos[\[Beta] Degree]}], 
     ImageSize -> {360, 275}]][[#[[2]]]] & /@ {{2, 1}, {0, 
   2 ;; 3}}), {{\[Alpha], 45}, -90, 90}, {{\[Beta], 60}, 0, 180}, 
   ContinuousAction -> True, 
   Initialization :> (pl = 
   Plot3D[Sin[(x y)]^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", ColorFunctionScaling -> True])]
```

and my result is the following:

[image]

The main problem with anaglyphs are the combination of colors in the image. Try to avoid many explicit reds and blues, or your pseudo-stereo image (plot) will suffer from ghost parts. I recommend a color scheme based on grey tones.

- Edit update

I have edited the code to be a bit more faster.

Comment: For generality it'd be better to use `ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[pl]`, so that one could generate `pl` with its size and aspect ratio, and then just display in stereo here in the same size.