# How to generate image/plot for view in red/blue 3d glasses?

Tags: graphics3d

How to modify code in post [Is it possible to produce anaglyphs with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9327/is-it-possible-to-produce-anaglyphs-with-mathematica/158203#158203) to view image from red/blue glasses?

Frankly i did not understand how ColorConvert and ColorCombine functions were used. Mathematica offers little guide relating to manipulating color channels.

Comment: What kind of image? I assume you have a 3d Image?

Comment: What kind of modification do you have in mind?  You'll get better help the more specific you are.

Comment: L/R perspective of the same scene and color coded according to Red/Blue or Red/cyan.

Comment: Possible duplication of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9327/is-it-possible-to-produce-anaglyphs-with-mathematica?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

I have tried with this after my post in the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9327/is-it-possible-to-produce-anaglyphs-with-mathematica/158203#158203) you provide:

```
photoanaglyph[imgi_, imgd_] := 
 ColorCombine[
  Flatten@(ColorSeparate[#[[1]]][[#[[2]]]] & /@ {{imgi, 1}, {imgd, 2 ;; 3}})]
```

and it works fine. I have been able to create some good (even better) images, such as:

[image]

Of course it is assumed that you have two images (left, right) having different perspectives, and having a good alignment.

Comment: These examples are for red/cyan only. I need for red/blue as well.

Comment: Easy, just change to `{imgd, 3}` in the code

Comment: p = Plot3D[Sin[x y]^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
{r, g} = ColorConvert[
    Image[Show[p, ViewPoint -> {3 Sin[#], 3 Cos[#], 2} &[# Degree]], 
     ImageSize -> {360, 275}], "RGB"] & /@ {141, 139}
photoanaglyph[imgi_, imgd_] := 
 ColorCombine[
  Flatten@(ColorSeparate[#[[1]]][[#[[2]]]] & /@ {{imgi, 1}, {imgd, 
       3}})]
photoanaglyph[r, g].                                                                                          I obtain a colour less output. What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: You have to combine three grayscale images. The process treat each image as a single array. If you have only two of them you need a third one having zeros to combine only red and blue channels (as green should be a zero array having the same dimensions of the images). As an additional information, I do no know why you have a red-blue image. Conventional red-blue glasses are not red-blue, but a red-cyan. Maybe, I am missing something...

Comment: Only Red/Blue were available at nearby shop and i was eager to test them.

Comment: Is something missing before [[#[[2]] ]]? I cannot figure out its purpose.