# Export 3D plot or Graphics3D object as stereoscopic 3D .jps file

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, graphics3d

I recently came across some Matlab code to output a 3D graph as a stereoscopic left/right .JPS file, viewable e.g. with [3D Media Viewer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Viewers/3DMediaViewer.shtml), [Stereoscopic Player](http://www.3dtv.at/Downloads/Index_en.aspx) or using any 3D television or beamer:
http://www.timzaman.com/2012/03/3d-matlab-save-stereo-3d-image/

I was on the lookout for a similar function that would export any Mathematica Graphics3D object or 3D plot to .JPS (which is just a .JPG with the image for the left & right eye shown side by side but with a different extension, as in
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:JPS-sample.jpg, i.e. a 3720 x 1080 pixel JPEG, comprised of 2 1860 x 1080 pixel images side by side).

Mathematica code to produce the two stereoscopic images for the left & right eye is given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30014/how-to-create-a-simple-cross-eyed-3d-plot), [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/StereoscopicViewOfPolyhedra/) and [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/3DAnaglyphGraphics/), so the problem is only how to combine and export these as a .JPS file? Should just be a question to `Rasterize[]` the two images, pasting the two images next to each other in one image, saving it as a .JPEG and then renaming the extension to .JPS (or something like that) - the first and last step I know how to do, but not pasting the two images next to each other. The analogous export to 3D PNG, .PNS would be cool too.

Anybody any thoughts?

Comment: You might want to post on http://community.wolfram.com/ as well, as this site will most likely not supply anything definite on WRI's development strategy.

Comment: OK I'll post the question there too!

Comment: You might also want to see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnExportConverter.html)…

Comment: Also posted the question at http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/515772?p_p_auth=ec2mHoM2

Comment: If you could provde the specs for these formats, joining two images should be doable ...

Comment: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/stereoimage/spec.pdf

Comment: To be honest I think it's just a matter of making a 3720 x 1080 pixel JPEG, comprised of 2 1860 x 1080 pixel images side by side, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#/media/File:JPS-sample.jpg, and just renaming the JPEG to a .JPS. I don't think the extra descriptor matters much, but I could be wrong...

Comment: @Tom I agree that the hard part of producing the projections for each eye has been essentially solved in [How to create a simple cross eyed 3d plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30014/27951). The rest of your question seems relatively simpler, so I would suggest closing this question as essentially a duplicated of that one.

Comment: Well I don't feel my question is a duplicate, as the part I still don't know how to do is to save out the two images to a .JPS file in Mathematica, so I would still be very happy if someone could show how to do that...