# How to visualize a Cayley graph in this style?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I'm trying to create a similar style of image like this one, which is the Cayley graph of $A_{5}$.

[image]

With Mathematica, I just can create the following

```
CayleyGraph[PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 5}, {2, 4}}]}], VertexLabels -> Placed["", Center], VertexSize -> 1.5]
```

[image]

It lost some stereoscopic feeling compared to the above one. Since I'm new to Mathematica, I am not quite familiar with this language. Could anyone help me improve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may try `Graph3D` to generate 3D-graphs. You can obtain a fog effect by overlaying the resulting graph with a semi-transparent `Image3D`. See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47944).

Comment: Something to start with `Graph3D@CayleyGraph[ ..., VertexSize -> .5]`

Comment: Thank you! @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: It works! Thanks!@Kuba

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simple way:

```
g = CayleyGraph[
  PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 5}, {2, 4}}]}]]
```

[image]

```
Graph3D[g, VertexSize -> 0.4, VertexStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

We can get something that looks more similar to your example by:

- Flattening the colours and disabling 3D shading: use `Glow` with your preferred colours and set the normal colour to `Black`.
- Thicken the edges. We need a new `EdgeShapeFunction` for this because edges are rendered as `Tube` by default, which does not respond to thickness directives.
- Add "fog" with Raster3D to fade the background.

```
edges = EdgeList[g] //

     Map[Style[#, Black, 
        Glow@First@PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeStyle]] &] //

    ReplaceAll[
     e : DirectedEdge[args___] /; EdgeQ[g, Reverse[e]] :> 
      Sort@UndirectedEdge[args]
     ] //
   DeleteDuplicatesBy[First];

vertices = VertexList[g];

g3d = Graph3D[vertices, edges,
  VertexStyle -> Directive[Black, Glow@GrayLevel[2/3]],
  VertexSize -> 1/2,
  EdgeShapeFunction -> (Tube[Line[#1], 0.05] &)
  ]

Show[g3d,
 Graphics3D[
  Raster3D[
   ConstantArray[.05, {10, 10, 10}], {Scaled[{0, 0, 0}], 
    Scaled[{1, 1, 1}]}, ColorFunction -> Opacity]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Here's another one with higher resolution shading:

```
Show[g3d,
 Graphics3D[
  Raster3D[
   ConstantArray[.02, 50 {1, 1, 1}], {Scaled[{0, 0, 0}], 
    Scaled[{1, 1, 1}]}, ColorFunction -> Opacity]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Warning: For some reason, increasing the Raster3D size from 50 to 51 disables the fog shading on my machine (M11.3, macOS 10.14.3).

---

At first I tried to create the corresponding polyhedron and set it to transparent white to fade the rear objects equally. The problem is that parts of them are outside the polyhedron.

It could be done like this with [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM):

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

Show[
 g3d,
 Graphics3D[
  GraphicsComplex[
   GraphEmbedding[g3d], {Opacity[0.7], Black, Glow[White], 
    Polygon[IGFaces@UndirectedGraph[g3d]]}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The missing piece is just the black silhouettes around the circles and the red arrows.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy I am not sure if that's possible with `Graphics3D`. Maybe with some image processing trickery.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy Maybe something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/rCpBW.png  Random-colour features, rasterize, edge-detect, dilate, overlay the edges on original image, downscale for smooth appearance.

Comment: We can attempt the same for just the nodes, but I don't like the result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AZxRx.png

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, that first image looks much better. I know it is possible to make arrows, I think you can render cones for this. Im not a regular Mathematica user tho.